# Read Events from Facebook with the Graph API

Tags: php, facebook

My Server reads the information about events via graph.facebook.com
This was no problem, because there was no Acces token for public events required yet...
Unfortunately Facebook changed this, so I'm not able to read the Information without an acces token.

My Server does not support the php extension curl, so I'm not able to use the facebook sdk :(

At the moment, I'm getting the information with:
graph.facebook.com/pageID/events
(The Page and it's events are public)

I have a valid acces token, but is it possible to use it as a param, like:
graph.facebook.com/pageID/events?AccesToken=XXXX

This would be a very simple solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is possible - try it!

You can add the `access_token` as a parameter like you have shown and use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve data from the Facebook API...

[Much of the documentation code samples](https://developers.facebook.com/search?selection=file_get_contents) use this method of `file_get_contents` to communicate with Facebook's servers - if its good enough for them, its good enough for us :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was searching for the name of this param a long time :)

Comment: No problem! :)  They use it in their documentation so you can take a look there for some examples...